# How to use qrfact function in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

In Julia, I would like to use the function qrfact(), which I thought was part of the LinearAlgebra package. However, when I attempt to use the function, Julia claims the function qrfact() is NOT defined. Is there perhaps any way I can use this specific function in Julia? I do not want to use the regular qr() function. I have attached a screenshot of the error message:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qrfact` was apparently deprecated to just `qr` before the release of version 1.0 back in 2018: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/27212

You don't say why you don't want to use 'regular `qr`', but since it's presumably the same as `qrfact`, it seems that's your only option.

If you are running old Julia code from pre-1.0, then a good course of action is to install v0.7, run your code and update it according to all the deprecation messages you get. After that you can safely transition to v1.x